# numpy.hstack() description

Tags: python, numpy

[In the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), this function is said to

> Stack arrays in sequence horizontally (column wise).

I don't really understand what "column wise" means exactly. Can someone explain it with the example code as provided by the documentation?

```
>>> a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
>>> b = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are both (3,1) shaped.  The result is (3,2) shape.  Arrays like `a` are often called column vectors; the result is a 2d array with 2 columns.  Print `a` to get a better idea of we mean by a column vector, or an array with 1 column.  For a 2d array, the last dimension is the 'column' one; `hstack` is `concatenate` on ``axis=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array A looks like this:

```
1
2
3
```

Array B looks like this:

```
2
3
4
```

Put array B *alongside* array A:

```
A B
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

This is your new array!